# Firestore rules variable in path compare to data

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, compare, firebase-security, rules

I want to compare a variable in the path with a entry in my document. I build the following rule:

```
match /{userId}/test/{cycle}/results {
  //allow read: if 3 == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/status).data.number
  allow read: if cycle == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/status).data.number
}
```

The commented out line works perfectly which means that the {cycle} variable in my path works and the correct number is transferred but when I want to compare the cycle variable with the number out of the databse it doens't work.

Is it possible that I compare strings with numbers or anything like this???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve it myself. The problems was that I compared a string with a Number. The path delivered by the request as a string which also defines the {cycle} variable as a string. I compared it with my data from my database which was a number...

Solution, convert the number into a string

```
match /{userId}/test/{cycle}/results {
  allow read: if cycle == string(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/status).data.number)
```

}

For more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String